# Javascript, Why there is no difference between print the string values from out side and inside the loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My result:

[image]

Code:

```
<title>Javascript</title>
```

```
<div id="tweetDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tweetString = "";


    var tweets = ["Lion", "Cat", "dog", "tiger"];

    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {

        tweetString = tweetString + "<p>" + tweets[i] + "</p>";

    }
    document.getElementById("tweetDiv").innerHTML = tweetString;
</script>
```

why am getting the same result when I print the tweetString from inside the loop and from out side the loop.

Comment: not sure what you ask :) ... but, because you declare a variable outside the `for` statement...

Comment: you are add new `<p>` to `tweetString` in each iteration. And `tweetString` is declared outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because `tweetString` is having global scope. When a variable has global scope it can be accessed by any function/variable anywhere in the code. If you define the variable inside the function/loop it will get local scope and you will be able to access the variable from inside the function/loop only and not outside. Use of keywords also matters, if you declare a variable using var inside a loop then also it will be having global scope, but define it using let, its scope will be limited to that block only

Global Scope

```js
var tweetString = "";


    var tweets = ["Lion", "Cat", "dog", "tiger"];

    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {

        tweetString = tweetString + "<p>" + tweets[i] + "</p>";

    }
    document.getElementById("tweetDiv").innerHTML = tweetString;
```

```html
<div id="tweetDiv"></div>
```

Local Scope (Defined inside the function / loop using let)

```js
    var tweets = ["Lion", "Cat", "dog", "tiger"];

    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
      let tweetString = "";
        tweetString = tweetString + "<p>" + tweets[i] + "</p>";

    }
    document.getElementById("tweetDiv").innerHTML = tweetString;
```

```html
 <div id="tweetDiv"></div>
```

Here when you try to access it from outside the loop you will get error

Answer (score 0):

**When using "tweetString" as local variable (inside loop):**

When loop ending the value of "tweetString" will be "

Lion

Cat

Dog

Tiger

".

And innerHTML replace old children elements to new elements.
So every loop the value of "tweetString" will replace to new one.

**When using "tweetString" as global variable (declare outside loop):**

After loop end the value of "tweetString" will append to "tweetDiv" one time with full sting without replace.